# Correctly encode link for RSS

Tags: html, xml, rss

I have the link containing `%3A` symbol:
`<a href="https://it.site.com/place/?symbol=TVC%3AFTMIB" target="_blank" rel="noopener">text</a>`

How to put the link corretly inside RSS's description tag?

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Noticias ahora</title>
        <link>https://www.europapress.es</link>
        <description>Noticias de actualidad</description>
        <language>es-ES</language>
        <item>
            <guid>GUID</guid>
            <title>TITLE</title>
            <description><![CDATA[
 
]]></description>
            <category></category>
            <link>LINK</link>
            <pubDate>Tue, 30 Mar 2020 18:12:54</pubDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

do I need encode/escape somehow the link?

Answer (score 0):

The description field can include only plain text. It doesn't support links.